# Concatenate text to get variable name VUE2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

In a Vue2 component i have a language array witch have all translated texts

```
"translated": {
    "oneText": "Text one",
    "twoText": "Text two"
}
```

I need to show the language text based in a received value from `item.number` the value can be one, two...

I try this but in the case `item.number` is `one` this return me `translated.oneText` value not `Text one`

```
<span>{{ 'translated.' + item.number + 'Text' }}</span>
```

And this obviously return an error when runs...

```
<span>{{ translated. + item.number + Text }}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
{{ translated[item.number + "Text"] }}
```